# Re-enable showing of a dialog before moving files to the trash in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, trash

I clicked on the "Don't not ask again" check-box of the dialog that was asking whether I'm sure I want to move files to the Trash, but now I've changed my mind and I'd rather have that back.

But I don't know where this setting is stored. How can I return to the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about Dolphin file manager.

The setting you're looking for is
*Control* → *Configure Dolphin...* → *General* → *Confirmations* → *Moving files or folders to trash*

[image: Screenshot]